# React material-ui tooltip hover over(fire an event trigger when the item is disabled)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, tooltip

i know that disabled item doesn't trigger any event and the possible workaround is to wrap my elements in another  which i tried but it didn't work. I can't think of another solution to hover over a disabled tooltip. Here's the sandbox i have

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";

export default function App() {
  const content = (
    <Tooltip title="hover over">
      <p>Hey</p>
    </Tooltip>
  );
  return (
    <MenuItem disabled component="div">
      {content}
    </MenuItem>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-wing-mgowh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 3):

In order to get the tooltip to show you need to wrap the disabled `MenuItem` with a `<div>` and then wrap it with the `Tooltip`:

```
export default function App() {
  const content = (
    <span title="lol">
      <p title="lol">Hey</p>
    </span>
  );
  return (
    <Tooltip
      title="hover over"
    >
      <div style={{ display: "inline-block" }}>
        <MenuItem disabled component="div">
          {content}
        </MenuItem>
      </div>
    </Tooltip>
  );
}
```

Checkout [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-q-63691972-0hqob) in which I also used `PopperProps` on the `Tooltip` in order to get it to show next to the `MenuItem`. You can play around with the `marginTop` and `marginLeft` values in order to adjust it to your use-case.